# Как в javafx выкинуть сообщение при (допустим) нажатии на кнопку?

Tags: javafx

Как в javafx выкинуть сообщение при (допустим) нажатии на кнопку?

Answer (score 5):

Начиная с Java JDK 8u40 диалоги [есть в стандартной библиотеке](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html). Простейший пример:

```
    import javafx.scene.control.Alert;

    ...

    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);

    alert.setTitle("Information");
    alert.setHeaderText(null);
    alert.setContentText("Hello World!");

    alert.showAndWait();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот хороший обзор доступных диалогов с примерами: [JavaFX Dialogs (official)](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/)

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться уже готовыми решениями для вывода сообщений в JavaFX:

1. [JavaFX Dialogs](http://edu.makery.ch/blog/2012/10/30/javafx-2-dialogs/)
2. [JFX Message Box](http://sourceforge.jp/projects/jfxmessagebox/wiki/FrontPage) (лично использовал)

Comment: дико извиняюсь,но как "подключить" jar-ник к проекту? тупо кинуть в src-папку и юзать
Dialogs.showInformationDialog(...)
не получилось

Comment: Нужно добавить путь к JAR-файлу в Class Path.
Если вы используете Eclipse, тогда: правая кнопка на проекте -> Build Path -> Add external jars

Comment: спасибо, в Eclipse я знаю как.... хотя уже разобрался и как в IDEA-е